# Laravel one to many relationship - get first relationship where it matches condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, model

In Laravel I have a Client model that has a one to many relationship with the model Activities. This relationship simply defines what activities need to be done for a specific client.

This is what I have in my Client model in order to get the activities relationship. 
I also have some conditions as I only want to grab the activities that are due to be completed for the client ordered by `fdate` (follow up date).

```
public function activities() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Activities', 'ccid')->where('fdate', '!=', '0000-00-00')->where('archive', 'n')->orderBy('fdate', 'DESC');
}
```

At this point I have some filters and I want to filter which clients to retrieve based on the activity type that needs to be completed on their account. For example I want to retreieve all clients that have an activity: **Sale**.

This is how I am getting all the activities that belong to a client where the type matches.

```
$clients = Client::with(['activities']);

if(isset($params['type']) && !empty($params['type'])){
        $activityType = $params['type'];
        $clients->whereHas('activities', function($query) use($activityType) {
            $query->where('type', $activityType);
        });
    }
```

Ideally when filtering I should retrieve all clients that have a Sale activity, ordered by the closest activity that needs to be done next (closest `fdate`).

This looks to be working somehow, but in some cases the client object has activities that are not only **Sale**.

How can I get only Sale activities for each client ordered by closest (`fdate`)

Answer (score 0):

The `whereHas` method will return clients with *at least one* activity of the type.
Instead you can use the inverse and say

```
$clients->whereDoesntHave('activities', function ($query) use ($activityType) {
    $query->where('type', '!=', $activityType);
});
```

This will return all clients that don't have activities where the type is not the `$activityType`

Comment: No luck with that

Answer (score 0):

Try approaching it from the Activities side of things:

```php
Activities::where('type', $type)->get();
```

You could also chain your `where()` commands to the end of it, like:

```php
Activities::where('type', $type)->where('fdate', '!=', '0000-00-00')->where('archive', 'n')->orderBy('fdate', 'DESC');
```

If you've defined your relationship both ways (one to many on Client, many to one on Activities), you should also be able to grab the client from each Activities model.

Plus, now that this is a Collection, you can do any other sort of filtering / sorting / grouping you need to on it.